# How to adopt asynchronous document opening with NSDocumentController in 10.6 & later

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Watching a WWDC 2011, I saw advice (but not an explanation) that one should

> Adopt asynchronous document opening

in NSDocumentController.

The video stated that since this feature was introduced in Snow Leopard (10.6), they would not explain further how to do this.

(Note I'm asking about async document **opening** not async document **saving**, which is a different feature introduced in 10.7 Lion)

This sounds vaguely familiar, and I'm sure I've seen how to do it in the past, but I've scoured a bit, and cannot now find how to do it.

Can someone please either explain in detail how to implement async document opening in NSDocumentController (apparently a Snow Leopard feature) or point me to the documentation on how to do this?

I suppose a pointer to Apple documentation would be preferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That video is likely referring to NSDocument's

```
+ (BOOL)canConcurrentlyReadDocumentsOfType:(NSString *)typeName;
```

[Here is Apple's doc on that](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDocument/canConcurrentlyReadDocumentsOfType%3a). And they also talk about this feature at the [top of that page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000008-SW5) and in the 10.6 AppKit release notes under the heading [New Support for Concurrent Document Opening in NSDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKitOlderNotes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000985).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, thanks Matt. I was searching for "async" or "asynchronous" when apparently I should have been searching for "concurrent". :|